# updating all cells in SQL table instead of the one selected in datagrid c# mySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to update my SQL table each time a value is changed in a data grid but all the values are changing instead of the one cell. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        try

        {

            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(connString);

            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(" update test.studentInfo set " +

             "name ='" + this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'," +
            "mobile ='" + this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "'" , conDataBase);

            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

            MessageBox.Show("Saved");


           conDataBase.Close();

        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)

        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can add button in the datagridview and insert your code there. I suggest also use parameter when transacting in db.

Comment: what does use parameters mean?@Vic

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter